# How to create a reusable button component with icons

Tags: angular, templates

I am trying to create a button template/component that can be reused accross the app. Also using text and icons that are set when the component is used accross the app.

My button.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() btnTxt = ['add item', 'remove item'];
  @Input() btnIconAdd = ''; // <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

button.component.html

```html
<button mat-button
        class="form-control" [attr.icon]="btnTxt">
  <!-- <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon> --> // this works but isn't what I need.
  {{btnIconAdd}} {{ btnTxt[0] }}
</button>
```

and then in another html template where the button is used (we'll call this 'other-page.component.html'):

```html
<app-button [attr.icon]="btnIconAdd"> // identifier not defined on btnIconAdd
  <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon> // this does not work here
</app-button>
```

So I have multiple problems here (like not knowing Angular that well..)

1. I want to reference icons from an array (or multiple vars) like I do with 'btntxt' OR be able to use  inside the  in the other-page.component.html file, where using  does not work.
2. Trying to set [attr.icon] - why can this template not access the btnTxt (even when it is set to single string, not an array)?
3. trying to use {{ btnTxt }} in the 'other-page.component.html' also yields an identifier not defined message.

Help greatly appreciated, and feel free to tell me 'you're doing it wrong'.

Comment: To pass inputs, you should do it like `<app-button [btnText]="yourVariable" [btnIconAdd]="yourIconVariable"></app-button>`, does that help?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to do as user184994 said, but with the icon it was slightly different.
Recap: trying to make a button element that can be used with differnt text, icons and calls to methods:

I simplified my button.ts file to no longer use an array of possible values:

```js
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() btnTxt: string;
  @Input() btnIcon: string;
}
```

and refernced `<app-button>` instead of button as pointed out by @user184994.
Also from user184994, I *correctly* refernced my attributes and vars.

In my 'other-page.component.html' file (**note the double and single nested quotes**, this to avoid setting the attribute value in other-page.comnponent.**ts**, instead being able to access the values from the button component ts file). "add_circle" is the icon name:

```html
<app-button-with-icon [btnTxt]="'hello'" [btnIcon]="'add_circle'">
</app-button-with-icon>
```

And then finally my button.component.html as below. One issue I has was to be able to specify an icon at the time of using the button, I couldn't place the icon markup in the other-page template, but instead had to place the markup in the button component template and refernce an empty string variable, then set the value in the template where the button is used (see prev. code snippet).

```html
<button mat-button class="form-control primary">
  <mat-icon>{{btnIcon}}</mat-icon>
  {{btnTxt}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a example in SB, maybe you can see if it is what you are trying to do, see the last item (Generic Mat-button with Icon )

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu

Comment: the stackblitz link is broken- this is why you should not post a link-only answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/332225